# Destroy specific table when using $.fn.DataTable.tables()

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have multiple tables on the same page, that are to be destroyed, when the user chooses to do so. My solution was to use

```
var table = $.fn.DataTable.tables()
table[i-1].destroy();
```

to get an array of all the tables and then just destroy the table at the given position. However it just responds with `.destroy is not a function` . How can I fix this?

Comment: How is the user picking which one to remove/destroy?  could just be that you need `$(this).closest("table").DataTable().destroy();`   from https://datatables.net/reference/api/destroy()   Similarly, what's `i` - if its `0` you won't have much luck.

Comment: `var tables = $.fn.DataTable.tables( { visible: true, api: true });
$(table[i - 1]).DataTable().destroy();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [destroy](https://datatables.net/reference/api/destroy()) api for it.

```
    var tables = $.fn.DataTable.tables( { visible: true, api: true });
        $(tables[i-1]).DataTable().destroy();
```

Here is sample [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/darjiyogen/n32sw0tx/6/)